# Is it possible to scan all folders and files in AWS S3 Bucket with public permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3

I'm wondering about storing e.g. **avatars of my application users**, it's not sensitive data, but is it possible that someone will get into my bucket (only files has a public read permissions) and get all of these files?

Structure of bucket:

```
avatars
  ...
  avatar[userID][randomToken][timestampUnix].jpg
  avatar[userID][randomToken][timestampUnix].jpg 
  avatar[userID][randomToken][timestampUnix].jpg 
  ...
```

Comment: If bucket is public, then anyway can access/download it content.

Comment: @Marcin I got it, but how it is possible to find our URLs?

Comment: any opinions???

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any opinion nor answer, as I don't understand the issue. If you hardcode your s3 urls in your website's JavaScript, then anyone can find them.